# Esconder value de input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Preciso esconder/remover o value do meu input, mas não estou conseguindo de forma alguma, onde estou errando? Muito Obrigado

HTML:

```
<div class="caixa-pesquisa">
   <div class="caixa-pesquisa-input">
      <input type="text" class="pesquisa-class" value="Digite o produto desejado...">   
         <div class="caixa-pesquisa-btn"><a class="btn-buscar" href="#">buscar</a></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function (){
$('.pesquisa-class').click(function(){if(this.value == this.defaultValue) {this.value = ;}});
$('.pesquisa-class').blur(function(){if (this.value == ) {this.value = this.defaultValue;}});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Não é mais fácil usar um campo do tipo `password`?

Comment: Mas assim ele criptografa meu texto, não?

Comment: Não, o valor vai em texto plano para quem receber os valores. Se vocẽ quisesse que os valores chegassem criptografados o ideal seria usar SSL/TSL, mas aí é um aspecto da conexão HTTP (HTTPS, no caso) e não tem mais a ver com a aplicação.

Comment: Mas no caso seria uma caixa de pesquisa de produtos,quero que o texto apareça para pessoa,para ela sabe o que pesquisou, Obrigado

Comment: Você está querendo simular um `placeholder`?

Comment: Ainda não entendi. O usuário vai fazer a pesquisa mas você não quer que o texto apareça? Isso é ruim do ponto de vista da usabilidade. Tente explicar melhor o que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: Agora que o @ErlonCharles comentou do `placeholder`, a pergunta faz sentido. É só setar o atributo `placeholder` no campo de busca com o valor que você quer que apareça inicialmente :)

Comment: Quanto a usabilidade: a menos que o usuário tenha algum problema vai ser difícil ele esquecer que é uma pesquisa, mesmo depois que o texto desaparecer. O que não pode é não mostrar (e é um problema que estou tendo um um tema de Wordpress, o foco, automático, faz o placeholder não mostrar).

Comment: O placeholder me atendeu, eu queria que quando o usuário clicasse na barra de pesquisa sumisse o value , esta perfeito agora. Obrigado!!

Comment: @CRAJ observe as respostas da pergunta e marque uma como correta, isso da reputação para quem à respondeu e independente de pra quem você marque isso também ajuda a comunidade a crescer :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Resposta:

Não precisa de nada do que você está fazendo, você pode apenas utilizar o atributo `placeholder` do `<input>` desta maneira:

```html
<input type="text" class="pesquisa-class" placeholder="Digite o produto desejado..." value="">
```

## Explicação:

Utilizar [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) pra fazer o que você precisa, não seria necessário pois os `<input>`'s do [html](/questions/tagged/html) contém alguns atributos que facilitam muitas coisas, dentre eles o `placeholder` seria o atributo mais indicado para o que você quer fazer.

O placeholder é a maneira mais moderna de informar o usuário o que ele tem que digitar no tal campo, anteriormente utilizamos Label's que seriam textos acima do campo.

## [Documentação do placeholder](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-placeholder-attribute)

## Compatibilidade:

Testado e funcionando nos seguintes navegadores:

- Mozilla Firefox (27.0)
- Google Chrome (32.0)
- Safari (5.1.7)
- Opera (12.16)
- Internet Explorer (IE11,IE10)

**Não funciona nos seguintes navegadores:**

- Internet Explorer(IE9,IE8,IE7)

## [Solução para navegadores não compatíveis](http://jsfiddle.net/RfK5h/2/):

Utilizando uma função chamada `placeholder()`:

```
function placeholder(str){
    $('input').css('color','#ccc');
    $('input').val(str);
}
```

Você deve executa-la uma vez ao carregar sua página:

```
placeholder("Digite o produto desejado...");
```

E deve atribuir estes eventos ao seu input, que seria `ao clicar nele`(click) limpar o valor dele, e `ao sair dele`(blur) colocar o placeholder novamente.

```
$('input').on("click", function () {
  var ValorAnterior = $.cookie("ValorAtual") || "";
  $(this).val(ValorAnterior);
});
$('input').on("blur", function () {
  $.cookie("ValorAtual", $(this).val());
  placeholder("Digite o produto desejado...");
});
```

Porém você tem que incluir o plugin [jQuery Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) (se desejar utilizar outra forma de cookie fica a sua opção).

Comment: Paulo, incrementa com alguma sugestão de fallback pra navegadores sem suporte ao placeholder

Comment: Paulo, concorda comigo que assim toda a vez que o usuário sair do input ele vai perder os dados?

Comment: Referente à solução compatível para os navegadores não compatíveis né ? Entendi, boa sacada @SparK ! vou mudar isto já :P

Comment: de uma olhada @SparK

Comment: Continua com comportamento diferente do padrão do navegador.
https://gist.github.com/SparK-Cruz/9096590

O uso seria $("input").placeholder();

Answer (score 2):

Seu javascript tem 2 erros, arrumando fica assim:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function (){
      $('.pesquisa-class').click(function(){if(this.value == this.defaultValue) {this.value = '';}});
      $('.pesquisa-class').blur(function(){if (this.value == '') {this.value = this.defaultValue;}});
  });
</script>
```

No `.blur` seu if estava apenas `if (this.value == )` sem o outro valor. No `.click` estava `this.value = ;` sem um valor para definir.

#### Código no JSFiddle

Answer (score 2):

Use o atributo `placeholder` no input.
Esse atributo só mostra o texto que você escolher enquanto o `value` do input estiver vazio.
Exemplo:

```
<div class="caixa-pesquisa">
   <div class="caixa-pesquisa-input">
      <input type="text" class="pesquisa-class" placeholder="Digite o produto desejado..." value="">   
         <div class="caixa-pesquisa-btn"><a class="btn-buscar" href="#">buscar</a></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

o que voce procura é um placeholder, neste caso, caso sua página suporte HTML 5, voce só precisa colocar "Digite o produto desejado..."  em um atributo placeholder,   o unico porém é que nem todos os navegadores suportam completamente o placeholder(IE), então tem a alternativa em javascript ou plugins do jquery , eu procurei no site em inglês, pois sei que vi uma questão parecida recentemente, mas não encontrei nada.

Answer (score 1):

Já que você está usando jQuery pode escrever o código desta maneira:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // armazena valor
    $('.pesquisa-class').get(0).defaultValue = $('.pesquisa-class').val();
    // limpa valor
    $('.pesquisa-class').click(function(){
        if($(this).val() == this.defaultValue) $(this).val('');
    });
    // recupera valor
    $('.pesquisa-class').blur(function(){
        if($(this).val() == '') $(this).val(this.defaultValue);
    });
});
```

Você tem que armazenar seu valor padrão pra poder comparar.

Para testar use o [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DU3fH/).

Em browsers modernos o tag `input` suporta a propriedade `placeholder` que serve exatamente pra isso que está sendo feito via javascript.

Comment: não funcionou amigo..

Comment: @CRAJ Coloquei um fiddle pra vc poder ver funcionando.

Answer (score 1):

A ideia é deixar um texto padrão para instrução do usuário e/ou label do campo a ser preenchido.
Como dito nas outras respostas, este recurso está disponível em todos os navegadores modernos através do atributo `placeholder`:

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="teste" />
```

Para navegadores mais antigos entenderem a atributo `placeholder` é necessária a utilização de um **[plugin](https://gist.github.com/SparK-Cruz/9096590)** (pode usar à vontade).
**O mesmo só é ativado quando detecta que o navegador não suporta placeholders nativamente.**

Answer (score -2):

**Use o `<input type='password'>` é bem melhor.. e quando você for pegar o valor dele ele te retorna como string, entende ? nada criptografado..**

**assim: http://jsfiddle.net/V4swX/**

Comment: Claro que não...