# Simular placeholder no IE8

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8

Estava lendo aqui a documentação e parece que o atributo `placeholder` não funciona no IE8. Teria algum modo de simular o `placeholder` que vocês utilizam?

Exemplo de HTML que não funciona no IE8:

```
<input type="text"  placeholder="NOME" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a solução descrita em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5910/3635

## [Solução para navegadores não compatíveis](http://jsfiddle.net/RfK5h/2/):

Utilizando uma função chamada `placeholder()`:

```
function placeholder(str){
    $('input').css('color','#ccc');
    $('input').val(str);
}
```

Você deve executa-la uma vez ao carregar sua página:

```
placeholder("Digite o produto desejado...");
```

E deve atribuir estes eventos ao seu input, que seria `ao clicar nele`(click) limpar o valor dele, e `ao sair dele`(blur) colocar o placeholder novamente.

```
$('input').on("click", function () {
  var ValorAnterior = $.cookie("ValorAtual") || "";
  $(this).val(ValorAnterior);
});
$('input').on("blur", function () {
  $.cookie("ValorAtual", $(this).val());
  placeholder("Digite o produto desejado...");
});
```

Porém você tem que incluir o plugin [jQuery Cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/) (se desejar utilizar outra forma de cookie fica a sua opção).

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Obrigado a você @PauloHDSousa

Answer (score 6):

Existe um projeto no GitHub com o objetivo de resolver essa questão:

### [Placeholders.js - An HTML5 placeholder attribute polyfill](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js)

Para usar o mesmo, é tão simples quanto incluir o ficheiro de Javascript na página:

```html
 <script src="caminho/para/Placeholders.js"></script>
```

<sup>**Nota:** Não requer mais nenhuma *framework* adicional, é Javascript nativo.</sup>

A vantagem é que podes ter a tua *markup* devidamente atualizada fazendo uso do atributo `placeholder="X"` e nos navegadores antigos o `Placeholders.js` vai garantir que tudo funciona tal como nos navegadores modernos.

Eis a lista de suporte que obténs ao usar o mesmo:

> - Internet Explorer 6 - 9 (com Placeholders.js)
> - Firefox 1 - 3 (with Placeholders.js), 4+ (nativo)
> - Opera 7 - 10 (with Placeholders.js), 11+ (nativo)
> - Safari 3.2 (with Placeholders.js), 4+ (nativo)
> - Chrome 4+ (nativo)
> - Flock 1.0+ (com Placeholders.js)
> - Konqueror 4.3 (com Placeholders.js)
> - SeaMonkey 1+ (com Placeholders.js)
> - Maxthon 1+ (com Placeholders.js)
> - SlimBrowser 5 (com Placeholders.js)
> - K-Meleon 0.7+ (com Placeholders.js)

Comment: Boa solucão @Zuul +1

Comment: +1 Essa e o melhor solução.

Answer (score 4):

você pode fazer dessa maneira:

```js
jQuery("input[placeholder]").focus(function(){
  if ( jQuery(this).val() == jQuery(this).attr('placeholder') ){
    jQuery(this).removeClass('placeholder').val('');
  }
}).blur(function(){
  if ( jQuery(this).val() == '' ){
    jQuery(this).addClass('placeholder').val( jQuery(this).attr('placeholder') );
  }
}).trigger('blur');
```

```css
input.placeholder{color: green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome" /><br><br>
  Telefone: <input type="text" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" /><br><br>
  RG: <input type="text" name="rg" placeholder="RG" />
</form>
```